# C# Winform checkbox button text

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a winform with a series of check boxes as buttons.

The datatype in SQL is a it

The checkbox is bound

When the value is true the text on the "button" says "True" when false it says "False"

I want the text to not change from what I type in.

EX;

Checkbox says
"Unit Active?"

When true it changes to True, I want it to say Unit Active? and turn green

Any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: I tried reading the text prior to binding then resetting the text
This is in a loop

sCAPTION = cb.Text;
 cb.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.bds_URL, sFIELD);
cb.Text = sCAPTION;

Comment: Your question is very hard to comprehend. Maybe show some code or images?

Comment: If you don't want the text of the checkbox to change, why are you binding it? Maybe you should bind the [`Checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx) property instead?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, You nailed it. That solved the issue.

Thank you

Comment: Great. I just posted it as an answer so others can more easily find it. You are also able to accept it to show others that your problem is solved, so they can move on to other answers that are yet unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are binding to the `Text` of the Checkbox. However, you specifically state that you don't want the text to change.

I think that you should bind to the [`Checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx) property instead.